# How to make a loading scene in between two scenes while downloading. Corona sdk

Tags: android, json, lua, coronasdk, scene

I'm working on a business app using corona. The interfcae is sort of like the gmail mobile app interface. You've got a screen with a table, when a row is clicked, it opens a new page.

**Description of interface:** The app gets text and imagelinks from indexed elements in a json object. For each element(jsonObject[i]) in the json object, a row is created and the images are downloaded from the link passed contained in the "imagelink" field in each json element, while texts are gotten from other fields in the same json element. I'm using sockets to get the image and store them in a temporary location that way the images download before everything shows up. And when a row is clicked, it passes the current json element (jsonObject[i]) as well as the tempimage downloaded, and on this new page, the tempImage and some other fields that weren't used in the table are displayed.

**Issue:** When moving back and front from the scene with the table and the page displayed when a row is clicked, it takes sometime to load up. Understandable since it has to download images, to help with this I created a scene called "loading" to call in between the two other scenes, For now it just has a plane white box (Screen size) that I want it to display while the next scene takes it's time to load, that way it doesn't look like the app is frozen.

**My problem:** The "loading" scene doesn't work, I know the app loads it cause I removed the part in the code that goes to the next screen, and the loading scene shows up, but when it's added back, everything transitions the way it did before, the current screen appears to be frozen and then goes to the next screen like the "loading" scene isn't there. Could I please get some help with this? I tried using "loadScene" before "goto" but I got a lot of errors. Thank you!

**My code:**

**ItemListPage.lua**

```
local composer = require ( "composer" )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local json = require( "json" )

-- Load the relevant LuaSocket modules
local http = require( "socket.http" )
local ltn12 = require( "ltn12" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

--To help with navigation, these two variables are set on all scenes except loading
--nextScene is the scene I want loaded after the "loading scene"
--prevScene is the current scene which will soon become the previous.
composer.setVariable( "nextScene", "itemDisplayPage")
composer.setVariable( "prevScene", composer.getSceneName("current"))

--NavigationBar elements initiated
--Removed for readability


--Load Json from local file
local filename = system.pathForFile( "items.json", system.ResourceDirectory )
local decoded, pos, msg = json.decodeFile( filename )

if not decoded then
    print( "Decode failed at "..tostring(pos)..": "..tostring(msg) )
else
    print( "File successfully decoded!" )
end
local items=decoded.items 
--items being JsonObject explained in queston

--image handler
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print ( "Network error - download failed" )
    end

    print ( "event.response.fullPath: ", event.response.fullPath )
    print ( "event.response.filename: ", event.response.filename )
    print ( "event.response.baseDirectory: ", event.response.baseDirectory )
end



--Table stuff
local scrollBarOptions = {
    sheet = scrollBarSheet,  -- Reference to the image sheet
    topFrame = 1,            -- Number of the "top" frame
    middleFrame = 2,         -- Number of the "middle" frame
    bottomFrame = 3          -- Number of the "bottom" frame
}


local function onRowRender( event )

    -- Get reference to the row group
    local row = event.row
    local params=event.row.params
    local itemRow=3;

    -- Cache the row "contentWidth" and "contentHeight" because the row bounds can change as children objects are added
    local rowHeight = row.contentHeight
    local rowWidth = row.contentWidth

    row.rowTitle = display.newText( row, params.topic, 0, 0, nil, 14 )
    row.rowTitle:setFillColor( 0 )
    row.rowTitle.anchorX = 0
    row.rowTitle.x = 0
    row.rowTitle.y = (rowHeight/2) * 0.5

    --Other elements removed for readabilty (it's all just text objects)

    --Download Image
    --params referring to items[i]
    local imagelink =params.imagelink

    -- Create local file for saving data
    local path = system.pathForFile( params.imagename, system.TemporaryDirectory )
    myFile = io.open( path, "w+b" ) 

    -- Request remote file and save data to local file
    http.request{
        url = imagelink, 
        sink = ltn12.sink.file( myFile )
    }

    row.Image = display.newImageRect(row, params.imagename, system.TemporaryDirectory, 25, 25)
    row.Image.x = 20
    row.Image.y = (rowHeight/2) * 1.5

    row:insert( row.rowTitle )
    row:insert( row.Image )
end

local function onRowTouch( event )
    local row = event.target
    local params=event.target.params

    composer.removeScene(composer.getSceneName("current"))
    composer.gotoScene( "loading" , {params=params})

end

-- Table
local tableView = widget.newTableView(
    {
        left = 0,
        top = navBar.height,
        height = display.contentHeight-navBar.height,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        onRowRender = onRowRender,
        onRowTouch = onRowTouch,
        listener = scrollListener
    }
)

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- create a white background to fill screen
    local background = display.newRect( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background:setFillColor( 1 )    -- white

    -- Insert rows
        for i = 1, #sermons do
            -- Insert a row into the tableView
            tableView:insertRow{
                rowHeight = 100,
                rowColor = { default={ 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 } },
                lineColor = { 1, 0, 0 },
                params=items[i]
            }
        end

    -- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
    sceneGroup:insert( background )
    sceneGroup:insert( tableView )
end

-- other functions and elements unused and removed for readability
```

**loading.lua**

```
local composer = require ( "composer" )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local json = require( "json" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

local nextParams

function scene:create( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view

nextParams=  event.params  

-- create a white background to fill screen
local background = display.newRect( display.contentCenterX, 

display.contentCenterY, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background:setFillColor( 1 )    -- white

    -- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
    sceneGroup:insert( background )
end

local function showNext(event)
    --go to next scene
    composer.removeScene(composer.getSceneName("current"))
    --Goes to next scene with parameters passed from previous scene
    composer.gotoScene(composer.getVariable( "nextScene" ), {params=nextParams})
    return true
end

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen and is about to move on screen
    elseif phase == "did" then
        showNext()
    end 
end

-- other functions and elements unused and removed for readability
```

**ItemDisplayPage.lua**

```
local composer = require ( "composer" )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local json = require( "json" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

--To help with navigation, these two variables are set on all scenes except loading
--nextScene is the scene I want loaded after the "loading scene"
--prevScene is the current scene which will soon become the previous.
composer.setVariable( "nextScene", composer.getVariable( "prevScene" ))
composer.setVariable( "prevScene", composer.getSceneName("current"))

--NavigationBar elements initiated
--This creates the "back button", when clicked it returns to the previous scene, in this case "itemListPage"
--it takes, no parameters
local function handleLeftButton( event )
   if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        composer.removeScene(composer.getSceneName("current"))
        composer.gotoScene( "loading" , {params=nil})
   end
   return true
end
--Remaning navbar elements removed for readability

function scene:create( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view
local params=event.params

-- create a white background to fill screen
local background = display.newRect( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
background:setFillColor( 1 )    -- white

--creating header bar
local bar = display.newRect( navBar.height + (headerBarHeight*0.5), display.contentCenterY, display.contentWidth, headerBarHeight )
bar:setFillColor( 1 )

-- create stuff
local title = display.newText(params.topic, 0, 0, nil, 14 )
title:setFillColor( 0 )
title.anchorX = 0
title.x = margin
title.y = ((2*headerBarHeight/2) * 0.5)+navBar.height

local Image = display.newImageRect(params.imagename, system.TemporaryDirectory, 25, 25)
Image.x = 50
Image.y = display.contentCenterY


-- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
sceneGroup:insert( background )
sceneGroup:insert( title )
sceneGroup:insert( Image)

end
-- other functions and elements unused and removed for readability
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your scenes are shown in following order:
`ItemListPage` -> `loading` -> `ItemDisplayPage`

But loading scene doesn't have any heavy work to do - so it is redundant.

On `ItemListPage.lua` you load images in `onRowRender` callback. This callback is called when you call `tableView:insertRow(...)` in `scene:create`. So there is the root of freese

I suggest you to create loading overlay on `ItemListPage` scene `create` event. Part of code with table creation should run after you show loading overlay to user - in `ItemListPage` `scene:show` event

```
function scene:show( event )
  local sceneGroup = self.view
  local phase = event.phase

  if phase == "will" then
  elseif phase == "did" then
    composer.showOverlay( "loading", { isModal = true })
    -- Insert rows
    for i = 1, #sermons do
     --put your code here
    end
    composer.hideOverlay( "fade", 100 )
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now

Comment: Hello, I seem to have hit a snag, could you maybe point me to a page that explains how to create the overlay you were talking about

Comment: @DrewU first you can try [overlay scene](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/system/composer/index.html#overlay-scenes). Open your loading scene as overlay should work - just remove `showNext` method from it. I edited my answer.

Comment: Hey man, so I tried this out, I don't know if the overlay is working or not but it still freezes on "itemDisplayPage" whenever I press the back button to go to "itemlistPage" after freezing up a bit it just shows "itemlistPage" instantly with the table and all that, any help on how to handle this?

Comment: I added print statements, so I know it enters the loading scene, it just doesn't show anything